# Checkout Transparente sai do site?

Tags: php

Baixei a biblioteca oficial do PagSeguro, PagSeguroLibrary, mas dizem que com o checkout transparente todo o processo é feita na loja virtual e toda a comunicação com o PagSeguro é feita via cUrl.

No entanto, não é isso o que ocorre pois no final do arquivo que chama a biblioteca temos um redirecionamento para a página de pagamento no site do PagSeguro.

Veja:

```
<?php
...
echo "<script>document.location='".$url."'</script>";

?>
```

Todo o código

```
<?php 

  $pedidoCliente = $pedidosClientesDao->pesquisaPedidoCliente ($_GET["idPedidoCliente"]);
  $itensPedido = $pedidosDao->pesquisaItensPedido ($pedidoCliente->getIdPedidoCliente());
  $cidade = $phpUtil->pesquisaCidade($conexao, $pedidoCliente->getCidade());
  $cliente = $clientesDao->pesquisaClienteId($pedidoCliente->getIdCliente());

  $ddd= substr($_SESSION["cliente"]["telefoneCliente"],0,2);
  $tel= substr($_SESSION["cliente"]["telefoneCliente"],2);

  require_once 'PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php';
  /** INICIO PROCESSO PAGSEGURO */
  $paymentrequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();

  foreach ($itensPedido as $chave => $item) {

      $produtoP = $produtosDao->pesquisaProdutoId($item->getIdProduto());
      $tipoP = $phpUtil->produtosTipos($produtoP->getTipo());
      $nomeP = $tipoP.", ".$produtosDao->pesquisaNomeProduto($item->getIdProduto());      

      $data = Array(
       'id' => $item->getIdProduto(), // identificador
       'description' => $nomeP, // descrição
       'quantity' => $item->getQuantidade(), // quantidade
       'amount' => number_format($item->getPrecoUnitario(), 2, '.', '')
      );

      $dataItem = new PagSeguroItem($data);
      /* $paymentRequest deve ser um objeto do tipo PagSeguroPaymentRequest */

      $paymentrequest->addItem($dataItem);

    }

   $paymentrequest->setCurrency('BRL');

////////////////q
  $paymentrequest->setShippingType(3);
  $paymentrequest->setShippingCost(number_format($pedidoCliente->getFrete(), 2, '.', ''));
  //Url de redirecionamento
  $redirectURL = "http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/retornoPS.php";
  $paymentrequest->setRedirectURL($redirectURL);// Url de retorno

  $credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();//credenciais do vendedor

  //$compra_id = App_Lib_Compras::insert($produto);
  $paymentrequest->setReference($pedidoCliente->getIdPedidoCliente());//Referencia;

  $paymentrequest->setSender(  
        $cliente->getNome(),       //nome
        $cliente->getEmail(),     //email  
        $ddd,       //ddd
        $tel,      //numero
        strlen($cliente->getDocumento()) == 11 ? "CPF" : "CNPJ",
        $cliente->getDocumento()
  );  

  $paymentrequest->setShippingAddress(  
        $pedidoCliente->getCep(),              //cep 
        $pedidoCliente->getEndereco(),           //rua
        $pedidoCliente->getNumero(),        //numero
        $pedidoCliente->getComplemento(),   //complemento
        $pedidoCliente->getBairro(),          //bairro
        $cidade["nome"],          //cidade
        $pedidoCliente->getEstado(),         //estado
        "BRASIL"             //pais
  );  


  $url = $paymentrequest->register($credentials);

  echo "<script>document.location='".$url."'</script>";
?>
```

Por Outro lado, usando um código aberto sem a utilização da biblioteca, consigo o mesmo resultado.

```
<?php 

  $urlAUT = "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout";
  $urlPGTO = "https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html";

  $ultimoPedido = $_GET["idPedidoCliente"];

  $pedidoCliente = $pedidosClientesDao->pesquisaPedidoCliente ($ultimoPedido);
  $itensPedido = $pedidosDao->pesquisaItensPedido ($pedidoCliente->getIdPedidoCliente());
  $cidade = $phpUtil->pesquisaCidade($conexao, $pedidoCliente->getCidade());
  $cliente = $clientesDao->pesquisaClienteId($pedidoCliente->getIdCliente());

  $ddd= substr($cliente->getTelefone(),0,2);
  $tel= substr($cliente->getTelefone(),2);

  $i = 1;
  $itensPS = null;

  foreach ($itensPedido as $chave => $item) {

      $produtoP = $produtosDao->pesquisaProdutoId($item->getIdProduto());
      $tipoP = $phpUtil->produtosTipos($produtoP->getTipo());
      $nomeP = $tipoP.", ".$produtosDao->pesquisaNomeProduto($item->getIdProduto());

      $itensPS["itemId".$i] = $item->getIdProduto();
      $itensPS["itemDescription".$i] = $nomeP;    
      $itensPS["itemAmount".$i] =  number_format($item->getPrecoUnitario(), 2, '.', '');
      $itensPS["itemQuantity".$i] = $item->getQuantidade();

      $i++;

    }

   $itens = "&";
   foreach ($itensPS as $key => $itemPS) :

       $itens .= $key."=".$itemPS."&";

   endforeach;

   $itens = substr ($itens, 0, -1);

   $post  = "email=".$constantes->getEmailPS();
   $post .= "&token=".$constantes->getTokenPS();
   $post .= "&currency=BRL";
   $post .= $itens;
   $post .= "&reference=".$pedidoCliente->getIdPedidoCliente();
   $post .= "&senderName=".$cliente->getNome();
   $post .= "&senderAreaCode=".$ddd;
   $post .= "&senderPhone=".$tel;
   $post .= "&senderEmail=".$cliente->getEmail();
   $post .= "&shippingType=3";
   $post .= "&shippingCost=".number_format($pedidoCliente->getFrete(), 2, '.', '');
   $post .= "&shippingAddressStreet=".$cliente->getEmail();
   $post .= "&shippingAddressNumber=".$pedidoCliente->getNumero();
   $post .= "&shippingAddressComplement=".$pedidoCliente->getNumero();
   $post .= "&shippingAddressDistrict=".$pedidoCliente->getBairro();
   $post .= "&shippingAddressPostalCode=".$pedidoCliente->getCep();
   $post .= "&shippingAddressCity=".$cidade["nome"];
   $post .= "&shippingAddressState=".$pedidoCliente->getEstado();
   $post .= "&shippingAddressCountry=BRA";

    $post = trim($post);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';

    $autenticacao = $phpUtil->recebeXMLHeaders($urlAUT, $headers, $post);
?>


<?php

if( isset($autenticacao->code) ) {

  $pedidosClientesDao->gravarToken($pedidoCliente->getIdPedidoCliente(), $autenticacao->code);

  $redirectURL = $urlPGTO."?code=".$autenticacao->code;

  echo "<script>location.href='".$redirectURL."'</script>";

} else {

    echo "<h1 class='erro textoErro'>Op's: ".$autenticacao["erro"]."</h1>";

}
?>
```

Será que o que estou pensando que é checkout na própria loja na verdade não é nada disso?
Será que não existe uma forma de conseguir isso?

Então tanto faz usar ou não usar a biblioteca. Estou cetro?

Detalhe: ambos os códigos funcionam corretamente.

Comment: O checkout transparente do Pag Seguro não sai do ambiente do cliente. É comunicação via API.
Como você disse, poderá usar cURL que vai te retornar um XML com os dados. No PagSeguro você precisa configurar a URL de Retorno do checkout, daí você retorna para um link do seu site. [Documentação PagSeguro](http://download.uol.com.br/pagseguro/docs/pagseguro-checkout-transparente.pdf)